# Mongoose model save() is getting stuck after saving to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a node application getting connected to `mongodb` using `mongoose`.
The application is working perfectly in production but in Disaster Recovery Server, the application is having issue.

In Disaster Recovery server, Node Application can able to connect to mongodb, fetch the data from database, but when coming to the saving statement i.e

```
console.log('debug1')
await test.save()
console.log('debug2')
```

The data in `test` model is getting saved in `test` collection properly but
after saving the execution of the flow is stopping, the save statement getting stuck after saving to database.

After I run the application, `debug1` is printed but not `debug2`.
I tested with other API also, there also same issue, storing in db but execution stopping.
No errors or exceptions getting logged.

I couldn't able to reproduce this in other environments and can't figure out the root cause.
Please help.

Comment: surround `await test.save()` in a try catch block, and console log error

Comment: It is already in try catch block. But no error getting logged @SuleymanSah

Comment: Do you have any mongoose middleware on the schema like pre or post?

Comment: I think there is no such middleware, 
This is how the schema is
`const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const test = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    applicationNumber: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    clientId: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
    strict: false,
  },
)

const test = mongoose.model('test', test)

module.exports = test `

Comment: What is `Disaster Recovery Server`? Is it perhaps a single node from a replica set that is in `SECONDARY` state? If so that would explain why you can read to it and not write to it. That would be a question about database management rather than Mongoose's save() functionality. If it is a `PRIMARY` but not all data bearing `SECONDARY` members are available, then you need to lower the write concern as the code is probably waiting for that confirmation which won't happen

Comment: Thanks for reply @user20042973
DRS is a server like production, it is having write access, as I mentioned data is getting saved in database but flow is not continuing after that

Comment: '_Getting saved_' is not the same thing as '_app getting confirmation of the write_'. If DRS is a standalone instance then this comment may not be applicable. But if it is intended (and configured as) part of a replica set, then [this behavior](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/write-concern/#wtimeout) is important, note "block indefinitely": _If you do not specify the `wtimeout` option and the level of write concern is unachievable, the write operation will block indefinitely. Specifying a `wtimeout` value of `0` is equivalent to a write concern without the `wtimeout` option._

Comment: Thanks @user20042973 After I added `await test.save({w: 1})` it is working fine for the save mongo queries. But I don't want to do the code update. So thought of making the change at global config level. Below is my replicaset confg
`"settings" : {"chainingAllowed" : true, "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10, "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000, "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1, "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000, "getLastErrorModes" : {}, "getLastErrorDefaults" : { "w" : 1, "wtimeout" : 0 }, "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("<some id>")}`

Comment: @user20042973 As you can see `{w: 1}` is already set at global config level. Why it was not working until I explicitly add at `save` query level?

One more thing in replicaset configs all three members have the same priority i.e 1.
Does this cause the issue?

Comment: What version are you using? They changed how you configure in the cluster a few years ago. Check out https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/setDefaultRWConcern/

Comment: Version is 4.2.8 @user20042973